# Callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

What is the problem with this code

```
var a=function()
{
   setInterval(function(){document.write("a");},1000);
}

function b(callback)
{
    callback();
    alert(2);
}

b(a); // alert 2
```

It should not not show me the alert because the call not over yet?

Comment: setInterval is asynchronous. It schedules the execution of the function, but returns immediately.

Comment: What was expected and what was the output?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the alert?

Comment: I get the alert but I learn that callback its first do the setInteval and after that thae alert or that I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is running as expected. SetInterval doesn't hold the execution for rest of the code it fires assigned function after specified time.

So you will get alert and then document.write.

Comment: so what is the use of callback?

Comment: As I mentioned before it will be fired after '1000' ms

Answer (score 1):

You could add the callback into your setInterval function so that it doesn't get executed until after the 1000 millisecond delay, e.g:

```
    var a=function(callback) {
        setInterval(function(){document.write("a"); callback(); },1000);
    }

    function b() {
        alert(2);
    }

a(b); // alert 2 AFTER the 1000 millisecond delay
```